# how to print multiple lables at correct alignment over roll by thermal printer

Tags: java, printing, awt

I'm trying to print QR codes on labels using pos80 thermal printer from java project using native awt print API, this is what the result looks like.

Please help me how to overcome this problem and print the QR codes in the middle of the label one after another.

I use javac 1.8.0_101 , netbeans11.0 , qrgen4 for generating QR codes.

[image: results are shown in snapshot]

The piece of code i used to read QR code image from dir and print via awt is as follow:

```
    public class PrinterService implements Printable {

    private PrinterJob printerJob;
    private PageFormat pageFormat;
    private Paper paper;
    private final int MARGIN = 1;

    public PrinterService() {
        printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        pageFormat = printerJob.defaultPage(); // Getting the page format.
        paper = new Paper(); // Create a new paper...

        paper.setImageableArea(MARGIN, MARGIN, pageFormat.getWidth(), pageFormat.getHeight());
        pageFormat.setPaper(paper);
        pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
        printerJob.setPrintable(this, pageFormat);
        try {
            printerJob.print();
        } catch (PrinterException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Printing Failed, Error: " + ex.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
        if (pageIndex > 0) {
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

        float marginTop = (float) 70.83;
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("qrcode75b75.gif");
        Image image = imageIcon.getImage();
        g2d.drawImage(image, 20, (int) (marginTop + 10), imageIcon.getImageObserver());
        g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());
        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your picture looks like you're using three different label forms.  Basically, you're going to have to adjust the margins in your print method until the QR code is centered.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc the problem is not with printing in the center, the problem is: if I want to print 100 labels at once, they are not equispaced one after another on label rol.  I showed 3 different types of rolls, and printer cuts the page when print is completed irrespective of taking care of label (the label is sometimes cut at the start, middle, end or anywhereelse)

Comment: When you define Paper, you have to specify the size of the labels.  Pick one label form, measure the size of the label, and specify that size as a page.  Each label is one page.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution is to use a printer with a stop mark printed on the paper, It is a black dot in the paper roll, printer reads the black dot and understand the alignment.